# Add explanation/description text below a setting in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui

In SwiftUI, what is the standard way (or the recommended way) to add "explanation" text to a setting. For example, in the screen shot below of the system Maps app's settings, the Speed Limit toggle has the following explanation text beneath it:

> Speed limit information will be shown when available.

[image: settings screen shot]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want something like the image you posted try `Form`. It can contain multiple `Section` where you can provide a `header` and a `footer` View.

[documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/form)

### Example:

```
struct TestView: View{
    var body: some View{
        Form{
            Section {
                Text("content")
            } header: {
                Text("header")
            } footer: {
                Text("footer")
            }
        }

    }
}
```

[image: exmaple]